# etoolbox conflict with bm package

Tags: etoolbox

I found a conflict between `bm` an `etoolbox` because later one redefines `\@@end`. It happens when it patches `\enddocument` command. 
Code from `etoolbox`:

```
\patchcmd\enddocument
  {\deadcycles}
  {\let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@afterenddocumenthook
   \deadcycles}
  {}
  {\let\etb@@end\@@end
   \def\@@end{%
     \let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
     \@afterenddocumenthook
     \etb@@end}}
```

`bm` package expects that `\@@end` will be from `latex.ltx` Shouldn't `etoolbox` redefine `\@@end` only on `\enddocument` (if `\patch\enddocument` failed)?

Example with the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\saved@enddocument\enddocument
\def\enddocument{\saved@enddocument}
\makeatother

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\sigma}$
\end{document}
```

Can it be fixed in TL1015?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are after here. You've deliberately altered `\enddocument` so that `etoolbox` can't patch it, leaving the 'fall back' of redefining `\@@end` as the only way to add a hook. It's not at all clear to me why you'd want to force this.

Comment: I've logged this as https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/issues/3: will think about it.

Comment: I redefined `\enddocument` just to show the problem. You can find a lot of  `\def\enddocument` definitions in TL distributions latex packages. And one of them raised me that problem.

Comment: OK, I'll think about it. (BTW, you've timed this well as I've just picked up `etoolbox` from a period of there being no maintainer!)

Comment: @JosephWright Wrap the “fail” argument in `\AtEndDocument`, but this won't work if the class has redefined `\enddocument` in some fancy way.

Comment: @egreg Possibly, though I need to check that those customised `\enddocument` definitions still honour `\AtEndDocument`. See also David's comments in chat about `\@@end`.

Comment: probably you can define `\outer\def\bm@end{\noexpand\noexpand\@@end}` after loading bm (inside `\makeatletter`..)

Comment: Yes, David, that helped.