# Conflict between hyperref and bm

Tags: hyperref, bm

Are there any ways to address the incompatibility below:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\section{Boundary conditions $\bm{H_F}$}
This is a test!
\end{document}
```

I get from TL 2016 and 2017:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

I have seen a few reports of conflicts between hyperref and bm, but they are always in the presence of {etoolbox} and they have been for the most reported as solved some time ago.

[etoolbox conflict with bm package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233945/etoolbox-conflict-with-bm-package)

[Package incompatibilites: etoolbox, hyperref, and bm, standalone?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22995/package-incompatibilites-etoolbox-hyperref-and-bm-standalone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Boundary conditions \texorpdfstring{$\bm{H_F}$}{H\_F}}

This is a test!

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also disable `\bm` in bookmarks, but you'll get a bunch of warnings.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\bm=\relax}

\begin{document}

\section{Boundary conditions $\bm{H_F}$}

This is a test!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this something correctable on {hyperref} or that is kept there intentionally that way? I am just trying to understand the reasons ...

Comment: @PauloNey There’s no typesetting in the bookmarks; `hyperref` does its best, but it can’t deal with everything.