# Using bm in Beamer Section

Tags: beamer, sectioning, bm

Forgive me if this is answered elsewhere, but my searches are failing me.

I am using section headings in beamer and want to include bold math variables in the heading.  This throws an error that I have not been able to fix.  A minimal example follows.  I am using a relatively fresh install of TeXShop (v. 4.44) on macOS.

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test $\bm{v}$} % Does not work
%\section{Test}  % Works

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error I get:

```
./mwe.tex:12: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \PD1\v.
```

It is successful if I use `\vec{}` or `\textbf{}` instead of `\bm{}`.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a hyperref issue, try `\texorpdfstring{$\bm{v}$}{v}` you might want to open an issue on the beamer bug tracker (I think it is hyperref related but probably best to start with beamer)

Comment: @daleif it fails with article too (if you load hyperref). So I think one can let beamer of the hook.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424084/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but with a completely different message. Article (bm loadded before hyperref) gives `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry`, and the MWE `Runaway argument?
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \PD1\v`

Comment: @daleif yes, but the source of the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ulrike comments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\section{Boundary conditions \texorpdfstring{$\bm{v}$}{v}}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]